# How to remove specific JS and CSS in Magento2 using page_layout/empty.xml

Tags: magento2, page-layouts

I have created New page_layout `empty.xml`. I need to remove some JS and CSS from this layout.
I already try `<remove src="print.css"/>` But it gives an error `Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Config\Dom\ValidationException): Element 'remove', attribute 'src': The attribute 'src' is not allowed.`

app/design/frontend/Sm/market/Magento_Theme/page_layout/empty.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_layout.xsd">
    <update handle="empty"/>
    
    <referenceContainer name="head" remove="true"/>
    <referenceContainer name="header" remove="true"/>
    <referenceContainer name="menu" remove="true"/>
    <referenceContainer name="notifications" remove="true"/>
    <referenceContainer name="footer" remove="true"/>
    <referenceContainer name="body" remove="true"/>
    <remove src="print.css"/>
</layout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the best example to remove js or css using layout xml files.

```
   <head>
    <!-- Remove local styles resources -->
    <remove src="css/styles-m.css" />
    <remove src="<Namespace>_<ModuleName>::css/styles.css" />

    <!-- Remove js resources -->
    <remove src="my-js.js" />
    <remove src="Magento_Catalog::js/sample1.js" />

    <!-- Remove external resources -->
    <remove src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" />
    <remove src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js" />
    <remove src="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat" />
   </head>
```

For more information,  you can see here, [Remove static links using layout](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/frontend-dev-guide/layouts/xml-manage.html#layout_markup_css_remove)

Please check like this and if this help you then hit like.

Thank you,

Hiren Patel

Comment: Your code will work for the layout file But I need the solution for the page_layout file.